# Twilio - Record calls made by Client

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call

How can I enable recoring for calls made by Twilio client js?

I am using Apex (Salesforce) to generate the token

**Javascript Code**

```
Twilio.Device.setup("{! token }");
```

**Apex Code**

```
TwilioCapability capability = TwilioAPI.createCapability();
capability.allowClientOutgoing(
    TwilioAPI.getTwilioConfig().ApplicationSid__c,null);
    capability.allowClientIncoming(UserInfo.getUserId());

public String getToken() { return capability.generateToken(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

This depends on what TwiML your Twilio Application is returning when the instance of Client connects to Twilio.

If you are returning the `<Dial>` verb, then you can include the [`record`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-record) attribute and Twilio will beginning recording the call when the second party picks up.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial timeout="10" record="true">415-123-4567</Dial>
</Response>
```

If you are not returning `<Dial>` then you can include the [`<Record>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record) verb in your response to have Twilio being recording the call.

```
<Response>
    <Record timeout="10" transcribe="true" />
</Response>
```

Hope that helps.